# How to fetch user's profile info related to user using laravel?

Tags: laravel

I want to fetch user's profile info related to user and i have already made relationship b/w user and profile one to one relation but I don't know how to fetch this?

Does anybody have an idea please help me thanks

**Database table**

```
Profile table has  User_name,phone_number,Job ,user_id
```

**controller**

```
public function viewprofile()
{
    return view('viewprofile');
}
```

**profile model**

```
class Profile extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'Profiles';
    protected $fillable = ['User_name', 'phone_number', 'Job'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

**User model**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
    }
}
```

**profile view**

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 d-flex align-items-stretch">
    <div class="card bg-light">
        <div class="card-header text-muted border-bottom-0">
            Digital Strategist
        </div>
        <div class="card-body pt-0">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-7">
                    <h2 class="lead"><b>Name: Your Name</b></h2>
                    <p class="text-muted text-sm"><b>Job: </b> Web Designer / UX / Graphic Artist /
                        Coffee Lover </p>
                    <ul class="ml-4 mb-0 fa-ul text-muted">
                        <li class="small"><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-lg fa-phone"></i></span>
                            Phone
                            #: + 800 - 12 12 23 52
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-5 text-center">
                    <img src="../../dist/img/user1-128x128.jpg" alt="" class="img-circle img-fluid">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <div class="text-right">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm bg-teal">
                    <i class="fas fa-comments"></i>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
                    <i class="fas fa-user"></i> View Profile
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: not  User_id use user_id on your profile table

Answer (score 3):

The users profile will be accessible through the relationship and you can get access to it by calling the relationship as a property:

```
$profile = auth()->user()->profile;
```

If you need to be able to display it in your view, then just pass it through:

```
public function viewprofile()
{
    return view('viewprofile', ['profile' => auth()->user()->profile]);
}
```